# Python 3.X combining similar lines in .txt files together

Tags: python

A question regarding combining values from a text file into a single variable and printing it.

An example I can give is a .txt file such as this:

```
School, 234
School, 543
```

I want to know the necessary steps to combining both of the school into a single variable "school" and have a value of 777.

I know that we will need to open the .txt file for reading and then splitting it apart with the .split(",") method.

Code Example:

```
schoolPopulation = open("SchoolPopulation.txt", "r")
for line in schoolPopulation:
    line = line.split(",")
```

Could anyone please advise me on how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
schoolPopulation = open("SchoolPopulation.txt", "r")
results = {}
for line in schoolPopulation:
    parts = line.split(",")
    name = parts[0].lower()
    val = int(parts[1])
    if name in results:
        results[name] += val
    else:
        results[name] = val
print(results)
schoolPopulation.close()
```

You could also use `defaultdict` and the `with` keyword.

```
from collections import defaultdict

with open("SchoolPopulation.txt", "r") as schoolPopulation:
    results = defaultdict(int)
    for line in schoolPopulation:
        parts = line.split(",")
        name = parts[0].lower()
        val = int(parts[1])
        results[name] += val

print(results)
```

If you'd like to display your results nicely you can do something like

```
for key in results:
    print("%s: %d" % (key, results[key]))
```

Comment: Hello wilbur. Thank you for replying and answering my question so fast. I do not quite understand the results part. Can we achieve the results just by printing it? For example: print("%10s : %10i" % (school, population))

Comment: `results` is a dictionary (or a defaultdict) that contains the different values from your text file. I've updated my answer to include a way to print it the way you ask.

Comment: I appreciate your effort for helping me. I can now utilize this to work with .txt files. You have a good evening wilbur.

Answer (score 1):

Python has rich standard library, where you can find classes for many typical tasks. [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is what you need in current situation:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter()


with open('SchoolPopulation.txt', 'r') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        name, val = line.split(',')
        c[name] += int(val)

print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
school = population = prev = ''
pop_count = 0
with open('SchoolPopulation.txt', 'r') as infile:
     for line in infile:
          line = line.split(',')
          school = line[0]
          population = int(line[1])
          if school == prev or prev == '':
               pop_count += line[1]
          else:
               pass #do something else here
          prev = school
```

Comment: First off I want to thank you for taking your time to post. Can I ask why prev was defined at the end? Wouldn't this cause a problem?

Comment: oh you are right I forgot to initialize it before the with statement.
please let me know if anything in the code is unclear :)

Comment: After messing around with the code you wrote, I can confirm it is a solid answer also. Thanks a lot for your help Seekheart.

Comment: you could pick my answer as the best if it was helpful :)